# Pulling data from a URL to insert in WordPress text

Tags: wordpress, url, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm just getting started with WordPress and have no prior experience with coding. I was wondering if someone could help me perform this task :

I am basically trying to pull data from a URL: https://equipelupien.com/partenaires-perso?calendly=jplupien&nomDu=stevenchose

I want the data `nomDu=stevenchose` to populate in a text field in WordPress. To give context, it's for a mortgage broker firm, and this page is made for a customer who wants to book an appointment referred by a partner. So in my text, we would read Fill out the form above to make an appointment with a broker referred by (here my data from URL)

Answer (score 1):

You pull the data [(the query string)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) from the [$_GET](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) array.

So to output in a text box it would look like this for WordPress

```
<input type="text" value="<?= sanitize_text_field($_GET['nomDu']); ?>" />
```

Some explanation:

- `<?=` is short for `<?php echo`
- `sanitize_text_field` is a WordPress core function that removes tags from the string that you cannot trust. `esc_attr` also could be used instead ([difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47544786/exact-difference-between-esc-attr-and-sanitize-text-field))

You could also add it as a shortcode:

```php
add_shortcode('nom-du-text', function(){
    return '<input type="text" value="' . sanitize_text_field($_GET['nomDu']) . '"/>'
});
```

Then you could use `[nom-du-text]` from the post editor.

Finally, to simple output this as text just add `<?= sanitize_text_field($_GET['nomDu']); ?>` to the page PHP template.